# How to insert content before pagination in loop?

Tags: loop, pagination

I need to insert code for a banner ad below the last post on each page of the loop, but above the automatic WP pagination. Currently, inserting the code after the have_posts check displays it below the loop and pagination. Is there a way to break out the pagination from the loop, so I can reposition it? I'm a PHP noob and googling this has not been helpful.

Here's what my index.php looks like:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="hero" class="home-slider">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider=2]'); ?>
</div>
<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" class="blog" role="main">
        <?php echo do_shortcode("[pro_ad_display_adzone id=2043]"); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php $count++; ?>
                  <?php if ($count == 5) : ?>
              <?php echo do_shortcode("[pro_ad_display_adzone id=2043]"); ?>
                    <?php endif; // end counter ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'post-teaser' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">

            <?php if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) :
                // Show a different message to a logged-in user who can add posts.
            ?>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'No posts to display', 'leapbase' ); ?></h1>
                </header>

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php printf( __( 'Ready to publish your first post? <a href="%s">Get started here</a>.', 'leapbase' ), admin_url( 'post-new.php' ) ); ?></p>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->

            <?php else :
                // Show the default message to everyone else.
            ?>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'leapbase' ); ?></h1>
                </header>

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'leapbase' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            <?php endif; // end current_user_can() check ?>

            </article><!-- #post-0 -->

        <?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<!-- ADZONE IN QUESTION BELOW -->
<?php echo do_shortcode("[pro_ad_display_adzone id=2043]"); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here are some illustrations:

[image: Current output from index.phpe]

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

Comment: Is index.php definitely the template being used there?

Comment: Yes; I've inserted "tester" code and such to verify.

Comment: where does your template call the pagination?

Comment: what's in the 'post-teaser' template part